# Radio button ngModelChange not firing

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, angular-forms

This should be basic and not directly related to kendoUI but given that I am still new to Angular need a bit of help to figure this out.
I am trying to databind radio buttons but because I have to do special processing I have to separate the data and event part. The event handler is not getting invoked. I do have the FormsModule imported.

```
<div class="col col-lg-11">
<form #positionTypeForm = "ngForm">
  <div kendoRippleContainer>
    <span *ngFor="let positionType of positionTypeChoices" >
        <input type="radio" id="{{office}}" name="positionTypeRadio" class="k-radio" [value] = "positionType" [ngModel] = "positionTypeFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterPositionType($event, positionType)"/>
        <label class="k-radio-label" for="allRadio">&nbsp;{{positionType}}&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

In the component class I have ...

```
public positionTypeChoices: Array<string> = ['Long', 'Short', 'All']; // grid filtering is case insensitive
public positionTypeFilter = 'All'; //  initial value
public filterPositionType(event: any, positionType: string) { // ... event handing}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked - the key is to keep these 2 same between the input and the label `id="type-{{i}}"` `for="type-{{i}}"`

```
                          <form #positionTypeForm = "ngForm">
                            <div kendoRippleContainer>
                              <span *ngFor="let positionType of positionTypeChoices; let i = index;" >
                                  <input type="radio" id="type-{{i}}" name="positionTypeRadio" class="k-radio" [value] = "positionType" [ngModel] = "positionTypeFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterPositionType($event, positionType)"/>
                                  <label class="k-radio-label" for="type-{{i}}">&nbsp;{{positionType}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the ngModel binding to be 2 way.
So replace [ngModel] with [(ngModel)]

```
<input type="radio" id="{{office}}" name="positionTypeRadio" class="k-radio" [value] = "positionType" [(ngModel)] = "positionTypeFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterPositionType($event, positionType)"/>
```

This way, the filterPositionType gets called once you select a radio button